# Form submission URL redirect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Trying to create two dropdown lists where the 2nd has a dependency on the first, and the second contains URL values with a GO button that goes to the URL. I need to implement this in Elementor.

I am following the guidance of this article: [Dependent Dropdown lists with go to url button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923978/dependent-dropdown-lists-with-go-to-url-button) and have created the following code, but the URL redirect part is not working. You can find the jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfsurbano/u26c0vb9/5/

When I implement this code into Elementor, the dropdown doesn't work either. What would be the possible reasons behind this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        $(function() {
    
        var $cat = $("#state"),
        $subcat = $(".subcat");
    
        $cat.on("change", function() {
            var _rel = $(this).val();
            $subcat.find("option").attr("style", "");
            $subcat.val("");
            if (!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled", true);
            $subcat.find("[rel=" + _rel + "]").show();
            $subcat.prop("disabled", false);
        });
    
        });
    
        function goToNewPage() {
            var url = document.getElementById('store').value;
            console.log(url);
            if (url != 'none') {
            window.open = url;
            }
        }
    </script>   
    
<div class="ranking-div">
    <div class="ranking-container">
        <p class="dropdown-header">請選擇你想查詢的<span class="dropdown-title">危疾保險排行榜</span></p>
    <div id="form-container">
        <form id="formname" name="Sate-Store">
            <select name="state" id="state">
            <option value="">保險類別</option>
            <option value="公司醫保">公司醫保</option>
            <option value="自願醫保">自願醫保</option>
            <option value="傳統醫保">傳統醫保</option>
            <option value="危疾保險">危疾保險</option>
            <option value="儲蓄保險">儲蓄保險</option>
            <option value="意外保險">意外保險</option>
            <option value="人壽保險">人壽保險</option>
            </select>

            <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="store" name="store">
            <option value>產品分類</option>

            <!-- 公司醫保 -->
            <option rel="公司醫保" value="http://www.google.com">公司醫療保險</option>

            <!-- 自願醫保 -->
            <option rel="自願醫保" value="www.google.com">標準計劃</option>
            <option rel="自願醫保" value="www.google.com">靈活計劃(附加醫療)</option>
            <option rel="自願醫保" value="www.google.com">靈活計劃(高端)</option>

            <!-- 傳統醫保 -->
            <option rel="傳統醫保" value="大眾醫療">大眾醫療</option>
            <option rel="傳統醫保" value="高端醫療">高端醫療</option>

            <!-- 危疾保險 -->
            <option rel="危疾保險" value="定期危疾">定期危疾</option>
            <option rel="危疾保險" value="儲蓄危疾(多次賠償)">儲蓄危疾(多次賠償)</option>
            <option rel="危疾保險" value="儲蓄危疾(全面多次賠償)">儲蓄危疾(全面多次賠償)</option>
            <!-- 儲蓄保險 -->
            <option rel="儲蓄保險" value="儲蓄保險">儲蓄保險</option>
            <option rel="儲蓄保險" value="派息保單">派息保單</option>
            <option rel="儲蓄保險" value="短期儲蓄">短期儲蓄</option>
            <option rel="儲蓄保險" value="傳承保單">傳承保單</option>
            <option rel="儲蓄保險" value="傳統延期年金">傳統延期年金</option>
            <option rel="儲蓄保險" value="可扣稅延期年金QDAP">可扣稅延期年金QDAP</option>

            <!-- 意外保險 -->
            <option rel="意外保險" value="意外保險">意外保險</option>

            <!-- 人壽保險 -->
            <option rel="人壽保險" value="定期人壽">定期人壽</option>
            </select>

<input class="btn-submit" type=button value="立即查看" onclick="goToNewPage()" />

</form>
</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) is a method. When you're calling `window.open = url;`, you're changing the definition of the function to a url string. Call it like this instead:

```
window.open(url);
```

Comment: That really helped! Thank you!

What if I want the url to open on the same window instead of opening a new one?

Comment: NVM i found it out!

it's window.location.assign(url);

Thank you Rifat!

Comment: You can also use `window.location.href = url` which I think is the most common way to open a new link in the same window. Please upvote the answer if it helped you. Thanks